# Finding Max value in for Loop

Tags: java, class, object

I'm a beginner at java and was just wondering how to find the max and minimum value from integers declared in a for loop (using a scanner to obtain user input) this program creates an object from a class Car and obtains information on the name, registration, colour and number of trips.

The number of trips prompts the for loop to print out odometer readings from 0 (odometer's initial reading) to whatever the variable carSample.numberOfTrips specifies.

I've tried declaring a new variable; int maximum = carSample.odometerReading.MAX_VALUE; (Then printing it)
aswell with minimum, however to no success; I receive the following error:

TestCar.java:25: error: int cannot be dereferenced
int maximum = carSample.odometerReading.MAX_VALUE;

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    car carSample = new car(); // Creates object of class Car

carSample.name = input.nextLine();
carSample.registration = input.nextLine();
carSample.colour = input.nextLine();
carSample.numberOfTrips = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {
    System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i) + ": ");
    int odometerReading = input.nextInt();
}
```

Any help or insight into how this can be peformed is really appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < carSample.numberOfTrips; i++) {
    System.out.print("Odometer reading " + (i) + ": ");
    int odometerReading = input.nextInt();
    if (odometerReading > maximum) {
        maximum = odometerReading;
    }
}

System.out.println(maximum); // Maximum value
```

Comment: by any chance how would i find the average of all trips? I know i could just take the odometer readings and divide by the length or x amount of trips, but i can't seem to figure out how to do that maybe odometerReading / carSample.numberOfTrips?

Comment: you can add `int total = 0;` before the loop. After the input in the loop update it with `total += odometerReading;`. And after the loop find the average with `(double) total / carSample.numberOfTrips`

Comment: thanks! i just tried it and it works. Cheers for your time and help man!

Answer (score 2):

If readings are for example 20 10 22 41 11

Do the first reading. 20

And use that value as your maximum and also minimum. So maximum = 20 and minimum = 20.

Then for the other readings, compare the reading to the current maximum and minimum and update the maximum and minimum accordingly.
E.g: second reading: 10. 10 is less than current maximum of 20, so no change in maximum. 10 is less than current minimum of 20, so update minimum to 10....and repeat for the remainder of the loop.